# Any way to weight paint a specific value?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I'm trying to use a grid mesh with a displace modifier on it to create a terrain.  I want to paint in the heights of this hill using the weight paint tool.  While this does work, it's hard to control.  The blender weight paint tool seems to only add or subtract a value of 1 from a circle around the cursor.  This makes it really hard to get an even mid range value.  For example, I'd like to create a plateau where all the points have a weight value of .4, but the brush tools make it difficult create anything smooth.

Is there a way to get the weight paint to target a specific value?  Alternately, is there a way to get the displace modifier to sample from vertex colors instead of vertex groups?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 2.79:

You can set the maximum value of the brush from the "Weight" option under the brush, from my experience the assigned weight will not exceed this value.

If you select a part of your mesh you can assign a weight ranging from 0-1.0 from the Object Data Properties tab. You can also see & modify the values assigned from the N menu's "Vertex Weights" tab when a vertex is selected.